# Add space between the radio button and lable in h:selectOneRadio and f:selectItems

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, whitespace, selectoneradio

I am using jsf2 with primefaces.

```
 h:selectOneRadio
               f:selectItems 
h:selectOneRadio
```

This produces a radio button and the input label inside the same td such as

```
<td>
   <input type=radio> </input>
   label 
</td>
```

My problem is I need to add space between the radio button and the label.
    (X)C121 Active
    (X)LRM

In the above radio button list I need to add space such as

```
(x)    <---Space-->  C121 Active
(x)    <--Space -->  LRM
```

What is the best way I can add space for this ? Need help. Sorry as I am new for JSF I could not figure-out a solution.
P.S (x) represents a radio button [image: Radio button and the label]

Tech Stack : JSF 2.0, Spring 3.x , Hibernate 4.x.

Comment: This is just basic HTML/CSS. Whilst JSF experts can answer it, it's technically better to reframe the question with a plain HTML/CSS snippet and retarget it at `[html][css]` users. Once you got the answer, then it's just a matter of figuring how to write JSF code in such way that it generates the desired HTML/CSS output.

Comment: Thanks, yet I am bit new to JSF. Basically if I can get this done by CSS would take that, yet my intention was to know whether there are attributes within the jsf tags to get this done.

Comment: HTML styling is supposed to be done by CSS, yes. Start at `<h:selectOneRadio>` tag documentation to learn about the available attributes to declare CSS style classes which should end up in the generated HTML output.

Comment: BalusC your point was spot on
table.radio_select input {
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: 120px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some styling like this would be appropriate:

```
input[type=radio]{
    margin-right: 7px;
}
```

Put it in `<style>`-tag in `h:head` or better yet in an external css-file you include with `h:outputStylesheet`.

This way, you'll target them all without further code.